# How to display filtered ArrayController content in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

**How to display filtered ArrayController content?**

There are many answers to this question on so but none of them seem to work for me (being an Ember noob).

I've create this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevTheDev/gu7aN/) and want it to display the filtered content withParent in the App.CategoriesController.  Currently it only displays blank.

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['sortOrder'],
    sortAscending: false,
    // filtered property
    withParent: (function () {
        this.filterBy('parentId', 1);
    }).property('@each')
});


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="categories">
    {{#each category in controller.withParent}}
        {{category.name}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu7aN/4/). I've fixed a couple of issues:

- Adapter declaration was using the old style, should be

  ```
  App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
  ```
- Templates are identified by data-template-name, not id

  ```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
  ```
- Added link to categories route. Application/index template, loaded on startup, was empty
- Fixed filter function

Comment: Thank you so much rallrall - that solved it after trying many many other alternatives

Comment: Forgot another thing. When doing calls to the store, use lower case model names. E.g. return this.store.find('category');

Comment: Thanks rallrall - I've just recently realised this and also that its important to  require that your server JSON is in snake case.